# How to use lilypond macros in different blocks

Tags: macros, lilypond

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
First variant

\begin{lilypond}
\version "2.17.27"
\language "english"
D = \relative d {d4 <f a d>}
A = \relative a, {a4 <a' c e>}
BassOne = {\D \A | \D \D |}
\new PianoStaff <<
  \new Staff  \relative f''{
    \time 2/2
    <f a>4 <f a> <e g> <e g> | <d f>4 <d f> <d f> <e g> |
  }
  \new Staff \relative{
    \time 2/2
    \clef bass
    \BassOne
  }
>>
\end{lilypond}

Second variant

\begin{lilypond}
\version "2.17.27"
\language "english"
D = \relative d {d4 <f a d>}
A = \relative a, {a4 <a' c e>}
BassOne = {\D \A | \D \D |}
\new PianoStaff <<
  \new Staff  \relative f''{
    \time 2/2
    f4 f e e | d d d e |
  }
  \new Staff \relative{
    \time 2/2
    \clef bass
    \BassOne
  }
>>
\end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

As there are 2 lilypond blocks, I have to duplicate this code:

```
D = \relative d {d4 <f a d>}
A = \relative a, {a4 <a' c e>}
BassOne = {\D \A | \D \D |}
```

Is possible to reuse it?

Comment: As far as i know you can place pretty much anything inside a macro, but if you use a macro inside a lilypond environment I do not know. Why dont you try? As one that have gone down that path before; for anything larger than a few bars could be usefull to make seperatly and input as graphics.

Comment: "f you use a macro inside a lilypond environment I do not know. Why dont you try?" - no, didn't work.

Comment: @Buschmann I managed to do it with creating a separate file and adding \include "bass.ly".

Comment: For your particular case, you can pack both variants into the same `lilypond` environment. That is, delete the first occurrence of `\end{lilypond}` and then delete from the second occurrence of `\begin{lilypond}` down to the second occurrence of `BassOne = {\D \A | \D \D |}`. The text `Second variant` now inside the `lilypond` block will be typeset between the first and second staff.